# alternative for strings combing strings that isnt "+"

Tags: java

Is there any way to join a string and another variable together, that is also a string, without using the "+" operator. Specifically one similar to this one that is done in C#.

```
string str = $"Hello {userName}. Today is {date}.";
```

If there is any way to achieve a similar or same outcome in Java please let me know.

Comment: @akuzminykh you can flag this question as a duplicate with the link you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

`String.format("Hello %s. Today is %s.", userName, date);`